# Why Laravel is truncating large text in the db

Tags: laravel, textarea, longtext

My table field is Longtext, however when I try to save a text of length equal to 3 page of a text book. It saves in the db but not complete. It truncates the text. What is wrong, do Laravel set default max length of a payload?
Is it a problem regarding my database?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

**Table Schema**

[image]

Comment: Show us your migration, please.

Comment: The controller's store method would also be useful in addition to the migration

Comment: The post updated.

Comment: There are various limits to consider. LONGTEXT can fit 4GB of data so that's probably not the problem. The default maximum POST size for apache is 2MB so if you're using apache and trying to post more than 2mb you'd need to increase that. The default maximum GET url length is probably around 8kb so if you're using a GET request... don't.